# MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException: 5.4.6 Hop count exceeded - possible mail loop

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm getting this exception when forwarding a mail between two mailboxes.

> MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException: 5.4.6 Hop count exceeded - possible mail loop

While forwarding email continuously between mailbox using Outlook, this doesn't seems to work using MailKit.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: What exception?   Can you show some code & where the exception occurs?

Comment: If you post the relevant code, we may have some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is simply surfacing an error received from the SMTP server. I think this error simply means that the SMTP server has detected that the message is being sent in a loop. Are both mailboxes the same? Does one of the mailboxes auto-forward to the other?

In other words, if you have the following setup, this might happen:

1. Send message to address A.
2. Address A is an alias for address B.
3. You receive the message at address B.
4. You forward the message to Address A.

This would cause a loop.

Comment: What seem to happen is that the "Received" header of the email kept increasing, which was detected as possible loop. Same might happen on the X-ClientProxiedBy header, which I also clear now :)